# Simple intranet site with embedded pages

Tags: html, iframe, embed

I'm trying to create a simple intranet style site for our internal users,  basically just a top navigation bar with all of our user facing internal sites along the top,  when they click on each one it will open the relevant site embedded in the page, maintaining the navigation bar at the top.

So far it is just a simple navigation bar like which opens each in a new tab:

```
<style>
#nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: -5 0 -5 -5;
padding: 0;
List-style: none;
background-color: #333333;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li {
float: left;
}

#nav li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 4px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-weight: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
         }

#nav li a:hover {
        color: #333333;
        background-color: #fffFFF; }
</style>

<html>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="http://intranet/glpi" target="_blank">GLPI</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://intranet/Redmine" target="_blank">Redmine</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://intranet/sms" target="_blank">SMS gateway</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://intranet/labelsregistry" target="_blank">Labels Registry</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

What I have tried so far is embedding it as an iFrame and an Object.  The iFrame will show,  but with no content,  the object will not even show!

The iFrame I was using to test is:

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://google.com>"</iframe>
```

This just shows a frame but with 'Internet Explorer cannot display the web page'.

Am I heading in the right direction, or is this a wrong usage of an iFrame?

My HTML is not the greatest!

[image]

EDIT :: The site is running on IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003 SP2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot link an `iframe` to an external site (across domains) - try making another page and iframing that page. The most likely reason for the `iframe` not working is because the target site (in this case, Google) is sending a header to prevent other sites iframing it:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

A lot of sites will do this to prevent a common vulnerability known as [UI Redressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) or [Click Hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking). Some sites will also include some frame busting Javascript as a backup security measure to the HTTP header.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options):

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>` or `<iframe>`. Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

**In short**: yes, your iframe is using the correct syntax, however you can only iframe to sites that are either on the same domain or that have allowed the use of framing through a header tag.

Comment: You are a genius.  For some unknown reason I decided to test it with an external site like Google, instead of the site I was actually trying to get to!  I tested with one of the internal sites and its working fine now.  Thanks

Comment: No worries, now you know for next time :). Best of luck.

Comment: **For all services on intranet using the same domain name it works**. So, you need to make subdomain DNS entries for each. 
For example if your Intranet has `intranet.company.local` address, create CNAME `helpdesk.company.local` for GLPI and it's done. 
For all other external services, let's use APis.